# Source of light

Tags: visible-light, terminology, reflection

Is this statement true" Chair is a source of light".

We know that there are two types of source of light(1) Primary source of light ( like bulb, candle) (2) secondary source of light ( like book, chair , pen).

So when we say chair is a source of light it mean. Chair is a source of primary OR secondary source of light.   So, my top most statement must be true.

Comment: What you call a secondary source of light is just an object reflecting light.

Comment: Is the chair on fire?

Comment: That gave me a good laugh @Dale

Answer (score 1):

"Chair is a source of light" is an English phrase.  Like many phrases, it has many meanings, and you have to ensure that the reader understands what you mean.

Niels points out that, for virtually everyone, "chair is a source of light" is considered to be a false statement because we typically are only thinking of primary sources.  However, you can contrive situations where it is very obviously the source of light.  If the only primary light source in a scene is a very bright light pointed at a chair, away from the viewer, the reflection of light off of the chair can actually light the scene behind the primary light source.  It's an odd situation, having a chair be a "light source," but we're more familiar with it happening with light off of walls.  It's actually quite common in every day life (or rather every night life) to have a wall that is lit by a primary light source you cannot see, and to have the rest of the room lit up by the reflections off of the wall (making it a secondary light source).  It also happens often when sunlight goes through a window and strikes a wall.  It happens so often that our brains often don't even notice it's happening.  (photographers train themselves to see the light in this way)

Speaking from a "does the reader understand you" point of view, "Chair is a source of light" would only be a phrase I would use if the chair was a significant attributing factor to the lighting of the scene I care about.  For example, in 3d graphics, there's a famous test environment called the [Cornell Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornell_box):

[image: Cornell Box]

If I were talking to a 3d graphics developer about that scene, I would be very comfortable using the phrase "The red and green walls are sources of light."  Indeed, a major aspect of that particular test environment is whether you properly model the secondary lighting that comes from those walls.

However, in this photo of Audrey Hepburn...

[image: Audrey Hepburn in a chair]

... I would feel very uncomfortable calling the chair a "source of light."  It is true that there are photons being emitted from the chair (reflected from the primary light sources behind the camera, mostly to the right of the camera), but it would be confusing to call it a light source.  The only reason I could think of to call it a "light source" would be if I made the trivial point that absolutely every object in the presence of a primary light source or secondary light source is, itself, a secondary light source.

Comment: On a related note, as you learn about thermal radiation and black body spectra, you will find out that *every* object that is at a temperature above absolute zero emits some thermal radiation in the visible spectrum, and thus can be considered a "primary light source."  However, unless you are explicitly talking about sensors that measure such things, people will be confused if you claim that every object glows.

Answer (score 0):

A chair can be a source of light. It could even be your only source of light if all other directions are blocked off. Light comes from energized electrons emitting photons. When a light bulb energizes the electrons emit photons that radiate out to the chair and energies electrons on the chair which also emit photons to your eyes. Both situations  emit photons, whats the difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you talk of light as the entire [Electromagnetic Spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum), then **YES**, *it is a primary source of "light"* as all objects in this Universe emit some form of electromagnetic radiation (as long as they are not perfect black bodies).

But by "light", if you mean the **"visible spectrum"**, then **NO**, a chair does not emit light.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to understand this:

1. visible light

If you are asking about visible light, then the chair is not a primary source of light (except for very special circumstances, like a wooden chair being on fire, or a metal chair being extremely hot glowing), but in normal cases the chair is only reflecting the light that is shining on it from a lightsource.

Now even in this case, the chair might do two things:

- reflect the light that is shining on it (elastic scattering)
- or absorb some light and re-emit it.

2. non visible light

Just put a IR camera on, and look at the chair. If somebody was just sitting on it, and heated it up (or sunlight heated it up), you might see EM waves coming from the chair. Those are not in the visible spectrum, but the IR camera transforms it for you. This means that the chair is not in thermal equilibrium with its environment and is emitting IR radiation. In this case the chair is a primary source of light (just not visible).